# Sort by multiple columns using get_posts

Tags: wp-query, get-posts, sort

I have the following:

```
get_posts(array(
  'post_type'             => 'event',
  'posts_per_page'        => -1,
  'meta_key'              => 'start_date',
  'orderby'               => 'meta_value_num',
  'order'                 => 'desc'
));
```

In case the date is the same, I want to order by `menu_order`. Is it possible with `get_posts()` or should I create my own `WP_Query`?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253005/how-to-order-by-two-different-things-at-once-in-a-query-in-wordpress) answer your question? Looks like you can put multiple items in the `orderby` parameter, so the value would read `orderby => 'date meta_value_num'` in your case.

Comment: I saw this answer, which uses `WP_Query`. My understanding is that `get_posts` is a utility function for `WP_Query`. I tried to pass several values with `array()` as shown in that answer and it did not seem to work, hence my question. It seems like `get_posts` is for simple queries only and that sorting by multiple columns qualifies as a complex query, but I can't find anything to confirm or infirm in docs or answers here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_key' => 'start_date',
    'meta_type' => 'DATE',
    'orderby' => array(
        'start_date' => 'ASC',
        'menu_order' => 'ASC',
    )
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Oh I was not aware of this syntax! I tried passing an array to both `orderby` and `order`... Thanks Artemy! Could you explain the other changes you made? (adding `'meta_type' => 'DATE'` and referring to `start_date` rather than `meta_value_num` ?)

Comment: @mrtnmgs well, I suppose that the start_date field on your website contains dates so it's better to specify the DATE type for ordering because by default WordPress doesn't handle dates this way